# DirectX Bootstrapper package

Tags: windows-installer, package, setup-project, bootstrapper

I want to share DirectX redistributable as a prerequisite package of my application setup msi( made with visual Studio).

Anyone developed a bootstrapper package of DirectX? Where can I find it? I need some help about it.

Thanks in advance,

Paulo

Comment: We did manage to do this, but I didn't personally do it. Will have to ask my colleague, who unfortunately isn't in for work today.

Comment: Ok, thank you, when you have some news pelease post them.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to add bootstrapper support for the DirectX 9c Redistributable (I wanted to do this for a ClickOnce setup.exe deployment):

1) Make this folder:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Microsoft.DirectX.9c

2) Make a product.xml inside that folder with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Product ProductCode="Microsoft.DirectX.9c" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper">
 <PackageFiles CopyAllPackageFiles="false">
 <PackageFile Name="dxwebsetup.exe" HomeSite="DirectXDownloadUrl" PublicKey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
 </PackageFiles>
 <InstallChecks>
 <FileCheck Property="IsD3dx9Present" SpecialFolder="SystemFolder" SearchPath="" FileName="d3dx9_33.dll" />
 </InstallChecks>
 <Commands Reboot="Defer">
 <Command PackageFile="dxwebsetup.exe" Arguments="/Q">
 <InstallConditions>
 <BypassIf Property="IsD3dx9Present" Compare="ValueExists" Value="true" />
 </InstallConditions>
 <ExitCodes>
 <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success" />
 <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
 </ExitCodes>
 </Command>
 </Commands>
</Product>
```

3) Make an /en folder and inside of the first one, and put this Package.xml in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package Name="DisplayName" Culture="Culture" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper">
 <Strings>
 <String Name="Culture">en</String>
 <String Name="DisplayName">Microsoft DirectX 9c Runtime</String>
 <String Name="GeneralFailure">An unexpected exit code was returned from the installer. The installation failed.</String>
 <String Name="DirectXDownloadUrl">http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/7/1/1718CCC4-6315-4D8E-9543-8E28A4E18C4C/dxwebsetup.exe</String>
 </Strings>
</Package>
```

Now VS will show the dx runtime as an option, and clients will download the directx runtime "web installer" from Microsoft's server and run it in /Q silent mode (also without the stupid bing bar.)

Answer (score 0):

I have not packaged the DirectX components, so I can't help you there. However, I have made custom bootstrapper packages with the help of these [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578914/add-prerequisites-dependencies-to-vs2008s-setup-project-options), [examples](http://www.thehat.free-online.co.uk/MSChart/), and [programs](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Add_Custom_Prerequisite.aspx). Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes those are useful links, I use them also to create other packages than DirectX, my question is about to know if DirectX is already installed on the machine and what componets of directX are really needed because the redistributable package is about 100MB.

Comment: Woah, yeah... I can see why you'd want to trim it down!